# Js animate right and bottom

Tags: javascript, animation

Hello I am having some difficulties animating right and bottom. I got the animate left code, but I am not able to animate right using javascript. Here is the code:

```
var right = $('#coolDiv').offset().right;

$("#coolDiv").css({right:right}).animate({"right":"0px"}, "slow");
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/

http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/4006/

How can I animate right = 0 and bottom = 0?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `offset` method return an object only with `left` and `top` properties.

So `$('#coolDiv').offset().right` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the width of `#cooldiv` and it's parent, subtract the width of `#cooldiv` from its' parent width can do work for you. Something like this.

```
var parentTag = $('#coolDiv').parent().outerWidth();
var coolDiv = $('#coolDiv').outerWidth();
var res = (parentTag - coolDiv) + "px" ;
$("#coolDiv").animate({"left":res}, "slow");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/4010/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This My Working code right to left div using click event

```
$(function(){
    var c=0;
    $("#coolDiv").click(function()
    {
        $(this).stop().animate({left: ++c%2*100 }, 'fast');
    });
});
```